# Desktop Icons won't display in all virtual desktops

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu

The icons I set in kubuntu are not displaying correctly, have been trying to find the configuration but the weirdest thing is that they display in Desktop 2 but not in desktop 1 which is the main one, I want to display them in all desktops.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by Desktop/Workstation.

Comment: Somehow they changed the name in the newer versions, they are now called "virtual desktop", the little boxes that lets you switch to different desktop views containing different apps running, so you send apps to different virtual desktops

Comment: You probably are using different activities. You would need to edit your activities so that all desktops show the same thing.

Comment: I tried to add them to my other virtual desktop, didn't do anything =/

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this solution... well I'm not so happy this one solution will make all icons appear within all virtual desktops.

First, `right-click one of the little boxes (virtual desktop switch box)`, and press `"Pager Settings"`. Go to Virtual Desktop section and deactivate `"different widgets on each desktop"`, then start adding your icons, they will be shared across all virtual desktops.

It's a temporary solution, I'm still looking for the right answer to have different widgets & different icons on each virtual desktop.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
Right click your taskbar and un-select lock taskbar then move it around to your the other screen and you will see your icons appear but not your taskbar then move it back and you have everything back to normal